# How to fix this Wifi problem in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: internet, connection, 22.04, router

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04. When I try to connect to my router WIFI can't establish connection, but when I share from my Android phone, WIFI establishes the connection and it works OK. How can I fix this router problem?

[image]

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ZfPkNBr i dont understand ..

Comment: Please copy/paste and format text instead of pictures of text. A picture (of text) can't be read on a text-only terminal, can't be copied from (edited, tried, and made to work), AND makes one take an action to even read your Question. Since we're all volunteers, some won't click. Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: i simply changed band from 2.4/5Ghz Standard to 2.4GHz and it connected and worked well actually !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this qualifies as "answer" or whether it should be a comment, but I think writing this as an answer should be fine...

It may be that you are also affected by a bug that's, at the moment, still part of 22.04 and preventing some wifi connections.

The solution is described in this [stackOverflow post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406799/wifi-access-point-broken-after-22-04-upgrade/1409170#1409170).