# Wifi access point broken after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: networking

I use my workstation as Wifi AP. I upgraded to 22.04.
Since then my laptop (also 22.04) does not connect to it anymore.
On the laptop (client) I get errors like

```
localhost kernel: [16342.804006] wlp3s0: deauthenticated from 50:eb:71:10:c1:56 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
```

Oddly enough my Andriod phone still connects fine to the AP after the upgrade.

The AP uses wpa-psk and was set up as in
https://gist.github.com/narate/d3f001c97e1c981a59f94cd76f041140

"nmcli device wifi list" on the laptop shows the AP broadcast as using both WPA2 and WPA3.
Perhaps can I try to disable WPA3 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an 'admin', so I can't provide technical feedback. I do not even understand what the output you quoted means. :)

But since I had the same problem (I believe) might still be able to help:

Apparently in 22.04 there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1958267) causing certain wifi connection to fail or slow down (for me, my mobile phone hotspot still worked, but my University's wifi did not).

Luckily, that "bug report page" also links a [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpa/+bug/1958267) with a really simple work-around! In a nutshell, that report explains which lines to insert into a certain file. It misses, though, to mention that the "wpa" needs to be restarted afterwards (or how that's done). I'll thus explain both here:

1. Open the file "/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf" as an admin.
2. Make sure all the following lines appear in that file. (For me, the first was already present)

> openssl_conf = openssl_init
>
> [openssl_init] ssl_conf = ssl_sect
>
> [ssl_sect] system_default = system_default_sect
>
> [system_default_sect] Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation

3. Restart wpa by first hitting `sudo pkill wpa_supplicant`, then `wpa_supplicant`

Hope that works for you too!

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I have come across that being mentioned and I applied those patches. So far no luck however, will try again.

Comment: A patch was released today for wpa_supplicant. We'll see...

Comment: I also have [networking issues after upgrading from 21.04 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1427974/562424). Not only with WiFi but also with Ethernet and USB-Tethering. `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` is a link to `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` here. All settings but the last were there. I added `Options = ...`, killed `wpa_supplicant`, it needs arguments/options to be started, which I don't know. I restarted Kubuntu. To no avail. Still not a single WiFi connection here. If this is already known since May is there really no official solution yet? How to apply a patch if there is no Internet connection?